# Validate user input with the postgresql database in JSP

Tags: postgresql, jsp

How can I verify the user login name already exist in the database in JSP? I keep getting exception error at PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FORM UserAccount").

```
<td><input type = "text" name = "user_name" value = "" /></td>
                        <%
                            String thatname = request.getParameter("user_name");
                            session.setAttribute("theName", thatname);

                            ResultSet rs = null;
                            // Verify if the username already exists in the database.
                            try {
                                //String userValidate = "SELECT * FORM UserAccount";
                                Connection conn = null;
                                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FORM UserAccount");
                                rs = statement.executeQuery();
                                while(rs.next()) {
                                    if(thatname == rs.getString("name")) {
                                        // do something
                                    }
                                }
                                rs.close();
                            }catch(SQLException e ) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            } finally {
                                if (rs != null) {
                                    try {
                                        rs.close();
                                    } catch (SQLException e) { } // Ignore
                                    rs = null;
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Show the *exact error text*. Also your table definition and PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, you have:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FORM UserAccount");
```

Try with a right Connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the preparedStatement,you have written FORM in the select statement it should be FROM. Exact syntax is

```
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM UserAccount");
```